# Null-aware .firstWhere, .singleWhere, .lastWhere in Dart's List?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety, null-safety

I often use `.firstWhere((E element) -> bool) -> E` in my project. When porting it to support null safety I couldn't cleanly handle a scenario when an element is not found in a [List](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.14.1/dart-core/List-class.html) instance.

`.firstWhere`, `.singleWhere` and `.lastWhere` returns `E`, not `E?` so when handling a case when a List does not contain required element there's no other way to return `null` other than casting a whole list from eg. `List<String>` to `List<String?>` which makes testing function worried about each element being potentially null, which it can't be. Before null safety I was able to just use `orElse: () => null` but with null safety `orElse` have to return element of type `E` so troublesome casting is required.

Do I have to have a `null` substitute for each type to use in `orElse` or are there other methods to make list checking support missing element scenario with null?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can just use [firstWhereOrNull](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/IterableExtension/firstWhereOrNull.html) which should work exactly as you expect.

Comment: remember to import collection.

`
import 'package:collection/collection.dart';
`

Answer (score 6):

The solution would be to create an extension on the `Iterable` type:

```dart
extension IterableModifier<E> on Iterable<E> {
  E? firstWhereOrNull(bool Function(E) test) =>
      cast<E?>().firstWhere((v) => v != null && test(v), orElse: () => null);
}
```

Then use it like this:

```dart
final myList = <String?>['A', 'B', null, 'C'];
String? result = myList.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e == 'D');
print(result); // output: null
  
result = myList.firstWhereOrNull((e) => e == 'A');
print(result); // output: "A"
```

[Try the full example on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=63468be73f6fe14239039236346ddd2e&null_safety=true)